# `..<`の動きについて

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

Swift2.2からSwift3に移行しており、NSMakeRangeを書き換える際にエラーが発生しました。
そのエラーは解消できているのですが、処理でどうしても腑に落ちない点があります。

Swift2.2

```
let data = "あいうえお"dataUsingEncoding(NSShiftJISStringEncoding)
let subData = data?.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 10))
```

Swift3

```
let data = "あいうえお".data(using: String.Encoding.shiftJIS) // 10bytes
let subData = data?.subdata(in: 0 ..< 10)
```

この場合、`NSMakeRange(0, 10)`なので`0 ..< 11`にして、0〜10の範囲を取得できるだろうと思っていたらエラーが発生し、以下のログが出力されました。

```
Termination app due to uncaught exception NSRangeException, reason: -[_MSInlineData subdataWithRange:]: range {0, 11} exceeds data length 10
```

今までの記憶では
`0 ..< 10` => `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`
`0 ... 10` => `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`
と考えていました。

なのでエラーとなったのが理解できません。

`for~in`では今までの記憶通りの動きをしてくれたので、この`data(using:)`の場合のみ違うということでしょうか？

Comment: Swiftの`Range`に対する認識に、まちがいはありませんが、Objective-C（というよりC言語の）`NSRange`に対して、誤解があるようです。`Range`は、開始インデックスと終了インデックスで指定しますが、`NSRange`（`NSMakeRange()`）では、開始インデックスと、**長さ**を指定します。この説明で不足でしたら、回答欄を使って、詳しい説明をしたいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

すでに nagonsoftware さんのコメントにありますが、もう少しだけご説明を。

`NSMakeRange(0, 10)`で表現される範囲は次のようなものです。

```
|<------------- len = 10 ------------->| 長さが10
[ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10][11]...
 ↑loc(開始位置)が0
```

一方Swiftの`..<`演算子は`(開始位置)..<(終了位置の次)`で範囲を表しますので、上記と同じ範囲を表そうと思うと、`0..<10`でなければなりません。

一般的に、

```
NSMakeRange(loc, len)
```

で表されていた範囲(`Range<Int>`)を、`..<`で表現すると、

```
loc..<loc+len
```

となります。